# I want to print a list of strings e.g. ["Lion", "hunts" "the" "animal"] as column(vertically) in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to write **javascript** function that takes list of strings e.g.
`["Lion", "hunts" "the" "animal"]`

expected output:

```
L h t a
i u h n
o n e i
n t   m
  s   a
      l
```

I want to print it on vscode.
I think i should be able to iterate but it didn't work.
i have tried this code below

```
function column(params) {
    var i, j;
    var put = "";
    for(let i = 1; i >= params.length; i++){
        for(let j = 1; j >=params.length; j++){
            put += param[i];
        }
        put += "\n";
    }
    console.log(put);
}
column(["Lion", "hunts", "the", "animal"]);
```

Comment: Where do you want to print that? What have you tried? What is your question?

Comment: i want to print to the console using vscode.

Comment: I have tried this but prints empty.

Comment: function column(params) {
    var i, j;
    var put = "";
    for(let i = 1; i >= params.length; i++){
        for(let j = 1; j >=params.length; j++){
            put += param[i];
        }
        put += "\n";
    }
    console.log(put);
}
column(["Lion", "hunts", "the", "animal"]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array = ["Lion", "hunts", "the", "animal"],
    max = [...array].sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length)[0].length,
    s = '';
for(let i=0; i < max; i++) {
    s = '';
    for(let j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
        s += (array[j][i] || ' ') + ' ';
    }
    console.log(s+'\n');
}
```

#### Algorithm i fellow:

Simply, i create a variable called `max` hold the maximum length of the array.
i get `max` with sort the array by length in descending order and take first,
since first is the longest word in array.
and create variable `s`
i use two loops *first for lines* and *second for columns*
i iterate over lines `max` times
i start by intial to `s` '' every line i iterate
and variable j loop over words in array and take the letter and store it in `s`
in respective order and if is not set it take one space,
and then concatinate them with space in either ways.
when loop j is over it show the variable `s` which represent line.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the concept. it is understood. I even try out another way which work.``` let array = ["Lion", "hunts", "the", "animal"];
var s = "";
for(item of array){
    max = item.length > s.length ?
          item.length : s.length;
}    
//max = [...array].sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length)[0].length;
for(let i=0; i < max; i++) {
    for(let j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
        s += (array[j][i] || " ") + " ";
    }
    s+='\n';   
}
console.log(s) ```

Answer (score 3):

You could get the maximum length of the words and iterate the array for getting the character at a certein position.

```js
let array = ["Lion", "hunts", "the", "animal"],
    max = Math.max(...array.map(({ length }) => length)),
    i = 0;
    
while (i < max) {
    console.log(...array.map(a => a[i] || ' '));
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, find the length of the longest word. This will determine how many (horizontal) lines you will print to the console.

Then, print each horizontal line iteratively. The `i`th horizontal line will print the `i`th character of each word. If the word has less than `i` characters, then just print a space.

```js
function printVertical(words) {
  const lengthOfLongestWord = Math.max(...words.map(word => word.length));

  for (let i = 0; i < lengthOfLongestWord; i++) {
    // Map each word into the `ith` character (or a space if the word is too short).
    const line = words.map(word => {
      if (i >= word.length) {
        // this word has finished printing, just print a space.
        return " ";
      }

      return word[i];
    });

    console.log(line.join(" "));
  }
}

printVertical(["Lion", "hunts", "the", "animal"]);
```